# php - checking whether a variable is set/ is true/ exists

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement

In my code I am checking whether variables exist. But it is not turning out the way I expect it.

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Retrieve `$result` from database.
2. Execute a block of code only if a result has been extracted (otherwise do nothing/skip over/move forward).

I used `if(isset($result))` but it doesn't seem to be working, looks like the `if` is being executed, even though it shouldn't when there is no data in $result. (but with problems because there is no actual `$result` variable to use in this block)

Comment: Can you post the code you use to do this as of now? It'll be much easier to point out the exact issue ...

Comment: Have you tried going with if(!is_null($result)) ?

Comment: Post the piece of code where $result is supposed to be initialized

Comment: I was checking the if on the `mysql_query` and now moved it to the `mysql_fetch_assoc`, and changed it to `if($result)` and now it is working. Thanks!

Comment: @omg ponies this happens to be a mysql question too, the answer actually was related to the result/s from a mysql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if there is any data extracted, use this :

```
$connect = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1",$sql_username,$sql_password);
$data = mysql_query($sql_query,$connect);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($data);
if($result) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the `if` on the `$data`, moved it down to the `$result`, and it's working now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't just `if($result)` work for you? If you have error reporting showing E_NOTICEs, then try `if(isset($result) && $result)`

Comment: I think this would depend on the query function used ... `mysql_query()` would return `FALSE` on failure, but others may not ...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are executing your query, there's a possibility you should be using `empty()` in place of `isset()`.

From the documentation:

> [isset](http://php.net/isset)
> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.
>
> [empty](http://php.net/empty)
> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty.

For example:

```
$var = '';
```

`isset($var)` would return true as it has been set, but `empty($var)` would return false because its value is an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Isset only works for non instantiated variables. When you set $result to the db response you are actually setting the variable.

You could instead use mysql_fetch_assoc ( resource $result ) or mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] ) depending on what you want to do. Both of those functions will return false if there is not a response.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like mysql_query it will return a resource, or false on error. That means it will always be set.